# How to add new products block to the product view page using local.xml

Tags: blocks, custom-block

I'm trying to add a new products block to the product view pages, I have several products marked as new & they DO show up on the homepage, for some reason they won't display on the individual product pages.

here is what I have in my local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">

        <block type="catalog/product_new" name="product_list_popular" alias="product_list_popular" template="catalog/product/product_list_popular.phtml">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setProductsCount"><count>8</count></action>
        </block>

        </reference>


    </catalog_product_view>
```

I have tried this in the content reference and by adding

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_list_popular') ?>
```

to the 1column template [and removing the reference from local.xml] - niether of these work.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are called child html then must be required parent block but your content not parent block

Comment: can you please tell me which location add <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_list_popular') ?> function ?

Answer (score 1):

try do some thing like this

in your xml add code

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_new" name="product_list_popular" alias="product_list_popular" template="catalog/product/product_list_popular.phtml">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setProductsCount">
                <count>8</count>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

And in your catalog/product/view.phtml file call child html

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_list_popular') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume,you have *trying to  call*  `product_list_popular` call at `view.phtml` and as per as magento *default behavior*

***catalog/product/view.phtml*** `template's layout alias name` is **product.info**.

As `getChildHtml()` only work whenever `product_list_popular` is *child block of product.info.*

and call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_list_popular') ?>` at view.phtml.

**You need to understand the getChildHtml() concept at magento.**

**For you requirement**,you need to change
`<reference name="content`">

to

```
<reference name="product.info">
```